# How to export all certificates in certification path (.P7B)?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on an export script. I am however stucked because unable to export my certificates by including those in the certification path.

[I would like to reproduce this option in my script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H27kr.jpg)

```
$ChainCertName = "fooCert"  # name of the certificate to export
$ChainIssuerName = "BarCert"        # certificate issuer

# search for a certificate which contains the requested name and provided by the requested issuer
$ChainCertListToExport = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\CA | ?{$_.Subject -Like "*CN=*$ChainCertName*" -and $_.Issuer -Like "CN=$ChainIssuerName*"}

foreach($ChainCertToExport in $ChainCertListToExport | Sort-Object Subject){

    # export P7B certificate
    $ChainCertDestPath = Join-Path -Path $ExportDirectory -ChildPath "Chain_certificate.p7b"
    Export-Certificate -Cert $ChainCertToExport -FilePath $ChainCertDestPath -Type p7b
}
```

I was able to see that some solutions could be found with the function **Export-PfxCertificate** but I have not yet found anything for p7b.

If someone had this problem, can you share your solution please ?

Comment: Dropped my answer, since we still do not have a match, the Export-PfxCertificate, does pfx, which means you need to use tools to convert that to P7b or as in my previous comment, look to external tools: Certutil - 
Export root and intermediate CA certificates in base64 format using PowerShell on the intermediate CA
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4e479fd-48b7-4659-ac02-6e7eadd1bdda/export-root-and-intermediate-ca-certificates-in-base64-format-using-powershell-on-the-intermediate or the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to export certificates in .p7b format use below command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\CA | Export-Certificate -FilePath c:\certs\CA.p7b -Type P7B
```

More details can be found at the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-certificate?view=windowsserver2019-ps).